# How to override boostrap 5 colors?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to uses scss file to override the [bootstrap's default colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/color/#theme-colors) like `bg-dark`.

I created a scss file and added the following to it

```
$dark: #061B36;
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";

$custom-colors: ( 
    "dark": $dark
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/accordion";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/offcanvas";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/placeholders";

// Helpers
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// Utilities
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
// scss-docs-end import-stack
```

Then compiled the code. However, the `bg-dark` color has not changed. How can I correctly override the colors used by bootstrap?

Comment: As is stated in [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#modify-map) you have to modify exact variable (`$dark`).

Comment: @Jax-p I added $dark in my code "I updated the question" but still not changing anything

Comment: Just change $dark and then @import bootstrap https://codeply.com/p/TPPFaq1KHi